# Showing notification banner on Mac with Swift

Tags: swift, macos, notifications

I tried to show up some notification banners on Mac OS with Swift. But i get them only in the notification center, not as banner.

Do you have an idea? Here my simple code:

```
func showNotification() -> Void {
    let notification = NSUserNotification()
    notification.title = "Title of notification"
    notification.subtitle = "Subtitle of notification"
    notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
    NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification) 
}

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
    showNotification()
    testLbl.stringValue = "Button was pressed"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You won't get a banner if your app is in the foreground.

Try using…

```
notification.deliveryDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.scheduleNotification(notification)
```

and then switch to another app

Comment: I put a sleep(5) in front of all code. But this is way better. Thanks!

Comment: "You won't get a banner if your app is in the foreground." Is there documentation somewhere to this effect?

Comment: you can receive in foreground as well, need to call completion handler with [.alert] argument in willPresent notification callback

Answer (score 2):

If, at the time of sending the notification, the app sending the notification is focused, then the notification won't show as a banner. An app can only deliver a banner notification if it is not active in the foreground.

Your code works well *when your app is not the main focus*, I've just tested it.

So, because you send the notification on a button click, the app is focused when the notification is sent: the notification only goes to the Notification Center, it is not shown as a banner.

This is a rule made on purpose by Apple.

Comment: Thanks mate! I tried it out and you are right.

I will look for another solution.