# Unable to show simple notification on macOS

Tags: swift, macos

Im Sort of new to Swift. I trying to create a console app/utility that creates a notification pop-up on macOS. I cant seem to find any way of doing this without. Its seems like this should be simple but im unable to get the notification pop-up to show :(

Im using swift 4.0.3 on macOS Sierra

Any guidance to get this work at the most basic level would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

```swift
import Foundation
import Cocoa

let notification = NSUserNotification()
notification.title = "Title of notification"
notification.subtitle = "Subtitle of notification"
notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/52080191

Answer (score 0):

Your notification is only delivered when your app is not focused.

If you want to deliver it anyway, you need to implement `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` as a protocol and these functions:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresent notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool { return true }
private func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didActivate notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool { return true }
public func userNotificationCenter(center: NSUserNotificationCenter, shouldPresentNotification notification: NSUserNotification) -> Bool { return true }
```

PS. I'm pretty sure, that not all of them are needed - but I don't know which ones are